# Octave's symbolic package (version 2.8.0) not working in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, octave

I have followed the options 1 and 2 of the instructions given here

https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/wiki/Notes-on-Windows-installation

Nevertheless, after loading the symbolic package I get

```
>> pkg load symbolic
>> syms x
error: 'python_ipc_popen2' undefined near line 59 column 17
error: called from
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 15
python_cmd at line 163 column 11
valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
assumptions at line 82 column 7
syms at line 97 column 13
```

Here is the output of `sympref diagnose`

```
>> sympref diagnose

Symbolic package diagnostics
============================

Python and SymPy are needed for most features of the Symbolic package.

The Python interpreter is currently: "/anaconda3/bin/python".

Computers may have more than one Python interpreter installed.  If you
need to, you can select a different one using the PYTHON environment
variable (see "help sympref").  For example, to use Python 3, try
    setenv PYTHON python3
    sympref reset

Attempting to run /anaconda3/bin/python -c "print(\"Python says hello\")"

Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
status =  1
output =

Unfortunately, that command failed!
We expected to see "status = 0" and "output = Python says hello".

  * Is there an error message above?

  * Do you have Python installed?

  * Please try using "setenv" as described above.

  * Most systems search the PATH environment when looking for commands.
    Your path seems to be: (...)
```

I have Anaconda 3 installed. I am working under Windows 10. Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Not sure but try installing [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and then install sympy (pip install sympy) ( Not using Anaconda)

Answer (score 1):

u should do setenv PYTHON full_path_to_python.exe

in my case that was setenv PYTHON C:\Users\username\anaconda3\python